# CSVReader headerReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(this.getClass().getResource(filePath).getPath()), delimiter);

Tags: java, maven, csv

i am working on java Maven framework and using CSVReader to read files but i dont understand, How "this.getClass().getResource(filePath).getPath()" fetches the absolute  path of the file and also what the function of delimiter(i.e ",").

Value of filepath is D:\read.txt

Absolute path is C:\Dev\03-24-15\AutomationTesting\src\test\resources\Data

CSVReader headerReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(this.getClass().getResource(filePath).getPath()), ",");

Please help!!!!

Answer (score 1):

A resource is not a file, and the result of `getResource().getPath()` is not a filename.

Use the URL returned by `getResource(),` get an `InputStream` from it, wrap that in an `InputStreamReader,` and pass that to `new CSVReader(...).`

Comment: Or just use `getResourceAsStream` instead of the first two steps.